# How to program a CSS3/JQuery/Flexslider carousel with visible sides

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

I am trying to design a large image and text carousel using CSS3, JQuery and Flexslider as per the following mockup:

http://onixbox.net/ClientTest/REDAP/REDAP_Website_Concept.jpg

So far I got all but the side images:

http://onixbox.net/ClientTest/REDAP/index.htm

I was inspired by Cnet.com's home page.

I have no idea how to change Flexslider to do this. Maybe three separate synchronized sliders? I am comfortable with HTML and CSS but I just know enough javascript/JQuery to plug in existing code and change some variables. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Onix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use a wrapper around the entire site in your HTML/CSS template setup so the wrapper around your flexslider can actually reach to the edges of the browser window
- Override flexslider's overflow:hidden style set on the flex-viewport div (it sets that with an inline style, so you'll need to use !important or change from JS after initializing flexslider)
- Use CSS to set the opacity of non-current images in the slider to a really low value

This approach should be able to get you very, very close to your comp.

Comment: I'm this apparently helped, post a link to the site when it's live.